# Memory profiling inside python ( function calling from Flask )

Tags: python, memory-management, flask, profiling

I have write a small app for ML purpose . So , I have to load a model from a file. Sample syntax look like (sample_1.py) :

```
model = cPickle.load(open("model_name.pkl"))
def analyzer(word):
    if word in model:
        return "something"
    else:
        return None
```

Now , Inside the flask app

```
from flask import Flask , jsonify , request , Response as resp
from sample_1 import analyzer

@app.route('/user_query_', methods = ['POST'])
def similar_to_query():

    if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
        answer = {}
        data  = request.json
        query_message = data["query"]
        result = analyzer(query_message)
        if result:
            answer["Result"] = result
            resp = jsonify(answer)
            resp.status_code = 200
            return resp
```

Now , I have to know , how much memory the model (from sample_1.py) is consuming. Most of the memory profiler and time profiler works as decorator over the function. Here , I can't load my model inside the analyzer function, as it causes the model to load everytime function is calling. I am not a Flask guy, so I better not modifying my code, but still any chance of finding proper memory profiling .

Comment: what's an `ML` purpose?

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvi-debugging-testing-and-profiling

Comment: Yeah . ML purpose means Machine Learning . I ended up executing it as  a seperate script and found out . Reading about flaskdebugger for making it automated in future .